# Implement speech to text in textfields flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Has anyone implemented Speech to text inside a textfield in flutter? I found this plugin but I cant get the example to run. I am using VSCode on windows for this build.

I tried this plugin - speech_recognition 0.3.0+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few small quirks with that [plugin/sample](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition):

- I had to comment out `_speech.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);`
- It didn’t implement permission requests, so for Android, I had to first manually enable it from the sample app’s settings. (or you can quickly implement [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler))

Otherwise, it is working. So for some simple testing, all you have to do is convert the `Text` that it uses to display the speech-to-text results to a `TextField`. This means changing these two lines and `initState()`:

```
child: new Text(transcription))),

void onRecognitionResult(String text) => setState(() => transcription = text);
```

To accomodate a `TextField` with a controller:

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController;

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  activateSpeechRecognizer();
  _textEditingController = new TextEditingController();
}

child: new TextField(controller: _textEditingController))),

void onRecognitionResult(String text) => setState(() => _textEditingController.text = text);
```

That’s it. Modify as needed.

Comment: how to append the speech output to existing text in text field because onRecognitionResult gets called multiple times?